# Pattern Matching Tags with RegEx and Python (re.findall)

Tags: python, regex

I need to match and apture the information between the pairs of tags. There are 2 pairs of tags per line. A
pair of tags is like this:

```
<a> </a> <b>hello hello 123</b> stuff to ignore here <i>123412bhje</i> <a>what???</a> stuff to ignore here <b>asd13asf</b> <i>who! Hooooo!</i> stuff to ignore here <i>df7887a</i>
```

The expected output is:

```
hello hello 123 123412bhje 
what??? asd13asf 
who! Hooooo! df7887a
```

I need to specifically use the format:

```
M = re.findall(“”, linein)
```

Comment: Do you actually need to use regex? you can use `beautifulsoup` can process things like this.

Comment: You are only showing one line in the input. Is there a reason why you are ignoring the first <a> </a> tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to ignore the first `<a> </a>` tag, the regex had to make the assumption that the first character inside of the tag did not contain a space, but the space was allowed thereafter.

**Here are the other assumptions made:**

- tag letters are in lowercase. eg `<b> </b> <i> </i>`
- information between tag-pairs can only contain `uppercase letters`, `lowercase letters`, `numbers`, and the symbols `! and ?`. If there are other symbols within the tags, then it may not match accurately.

**Here is a working version based on your example:**

```py
import re

linein = '<a> </a> <b>hello hello 123</b> stuff to ignore here <i>123412bhje</i> <a>what???</a> stuff to ignore here <b>asd13asf</b> <i>who! Hooooo!</i> stuff to ignore here <i>df7887a</i>'
M = re.findall(r'<[a-z]+>([A-Za-z0-9?!][[A-Za-z0-9?!\s]*)</[a-z]>', linein)

for i in range(0,len(M),2):
    print(M[i],M[i+1])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
hello hello 123 123412bhje
what??? asd13asf
who! Hooooo! df7887a
```